# EF 4.1: Find Key Property Type from Code First with Fluent Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm using EF 4.1 Code First, with a Fluent Mapping:

Entity:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyClassID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class MyClassMapping: EntityTypeConfiguration<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMapping()
    {
        Map(t => t.ToTable("MyClass"))
             .HasKey(t => t.MyClassID);

        Property(t => t.MyClassID)
             .IsRequired()
             .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(t => t.Name)
             .IsRequired()
             .HasMaxLength(200);
    }
}
```

Given this configuration (and a number of similar declarations/mappings for other entities), if I know the type of the entity class (ie `MyClass`) is it possible to get the Type and Name of the key property of the entity class? - Since I've defined it in the mapping, shouldn't I be able to get this back from either `IDbSet` for `MyClass` or my `DbContext` derived Entity container?

I'm not interested in just assuming that `keyname = classname + "ID"` or similar - how is it done properly from the mappings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the [MetadataWorkspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace.aspx)

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

    public void Test()
    {            
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

        var mdw = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        var items = mdw.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace);
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class Name: {0}", i.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Key Property Names:");
            foreach (var key in i.KeyMembers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key.Name);
            }
        }
 }
```